# Is there any new developments on the Barnette's conjecture?

Tags: graph-theory, polyhedra, planar-graphs, bipartite-graphs, hamiltonian-path

When I searching for interesting math problems. I find there is a graph theory conjecture called the Barnette's conjecture.

The statement is: **Is every bipartite simple polyhedron Hamiltonian?**

A early version which is proven to be false is: **(Tait's conjecture) Is every 3-connected planar cubic graph has a Hamiltonian cycle through all its vertices?**

The Tait's conjecture is disproved by Tutte graph.

[image]

But it is mentioned on the wiki page that there are smaller counterexamples. What are they? I couldn't find the paper.

And also, is there any other approaches approaching this problem?

Thank you very much for any form of help.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tait%27s_conjecture#CITEREFHoltonMcKay1988 this reference is suggested as the minimal counterexample to Tait's Conjecture